# Locate Widget for flexviewer 2.3.1

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

I want to exclude addresses to the state of Oregon.
Pre 2.3.1 code was

```
<listfield>State</listfield>
<listvalues>OR</listvalues>
```

for 2.3.1 ESRI says to use

```
<fields>State</fields>
<fields listvalues="OR">
```

but no dropdown shows up, and it still searches all of US?

Comment: does it require more than one value to become a dropdown?

Comment: i tried and still no dice
<locator>http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/TA_Streets_US/GeocodeServer</locator>
    <minscore>40</minscore>
 <fields>State</fields>
 <fields>City</fields>
    <fields listvalues= "OR, CA"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
<fields><field name="State" defaultvalue="OR" visible="false"/></fields>
```

Comment: This worked for me as well.  That, and I didn't have the <usesingleline> tag set to false.  Thanks.

Also, you can mark your own answers as accepted if you want to, to show that the question has been answered successfully.